# Move android-sdk directory to /home partition?

Tags: android, linux

I am running out of space on my root partition and would like to move android-sdk directory from /opt to /home.

How do I do that? What do I need to add to .bashrc for android SDK to know new path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your new path in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-directory
```

Then you can directly set in a console :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

for changes to take effect.

Comment: This what worked for me: `export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-directory/tools`